# SQL server removing traling zero after decimal points in a string

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following variable:

```
DECLARE @test nvarchar(100)
SET @test =  'Prodcut A (Average: 1.000)'
SET @test =  'Prodcut B (Average: 2.3500)'
```

My output should be: Prodcut A (Avegrage: 1.0), Prodcut B (Avegrage: 2.35)

How can I remove all trailing zeros zeros from a nvarchar datatype column in SQL Server?
I am sure that I have to use SUBSTRING and CHARINDEX but not sure how. Can someone please help me?

I have tried the following:

```
IF charindex('.', @test ) > 0 
   select  SUBSTRING(@test, PATINDEX('%[^0 ]%', @test+ ' '), LEN(@test))                    
End
```

Comment: Do you mean `trailing` zeroes?

Comment: @Quassnoi the op update the tag and the title, before didn't metion engine

Comment: will column always be constructed with "Average:" + number + ")"?

Comment: Yes. The column is defined as NVARCHAR the values sometimes be like "Average:" + number + ")"

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over the string with a look to find the position of the last non-'0' character, but that's a mess.

*With the caveat that you might run into occasional floating-point errors,* this will do what you want:

```
convert(varchar, convert(float, '123.40')) -- yields '123.4'
convert(varchar, convert(float, @test))
```

Comment: With the requirements described be the OT, occasional would rather be regular ;-)

Comment: Blech.  You're right, I optimized away the fact that the string is already fully composed.

Answer (score 1):

If the structure is always the same you might use something like this:

```
Declare @a Table (test varchar(100))
Insert into @a Values ('Prodcut X ')
Insert into @a Values ('Prodcut A (Average: 1.000)')
Insert into @a Values ('Prodcut B (Average: 2.3500)')
Insert into @a Values ('Prodcut C (Average: 2.0510)')


Select  
Case When charindex('.', test ) > 0 then
   LEFT(test, LEN(test) + 1  - 
   Case When 
      PATINDEX('%[1-9]%', Reverse(test) + ' ')
    > PATINDEX('%[.]%', Reverse(test) + ' ')
    then PATINDEX('%[.]%', Reverse(test) + ' ') - 1
    else PATINDEX('%[1-9]%', Reverse(test) + ' ') 
    end 
    ) +')'
else test end
from @a
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming

> Yes. The column is defined as NVARCHAR the values sometimes be like
>   "Average:" + number + ")"

you can convert `number` from `decimal` type to `float`, because `float` is printed without trailing zeros:

```
'Average:' + cast(number as float) + ')'
```

But there's a known localization problem (i.e. it appears for some non-English versions, e.g. for Russian version) when `decimal` has `.` as separator and `float` type has `,`. In this case you need:

```
'Average:' + replace(cast(cast(number as float) as nvarchar), ',', '.') + ')'
```

, i.e. to replace comma to dot.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 DECLARE @test nvarchar(100)
SET @test =  'Prodcut A (Average: ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,CAST(1.000 as float))+')'
SET @test =  'Prodcut B (Average: ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,CAST(2.3500 as float))+')'
SELECT @test
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code.

```
DECLARE @test nvarchar(100)
SET @test =  'Prodcut A (Average: ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,CAST(1.000 as float))+')'

SELECT @test
```